# Elastic Beanstalk application version issues

Tags: github-actions, amazon-elb

I am struggling with an issue trying to deploy a new application to Elastic Beanstalk using GitHub action. I always get this error:

> Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Degraded. Command failed on all instances. Incorrect application version found on all instances

The main question here is: how can I manage, customize etc. the application versions? When I created the environment, I chose the sampler application and after that I tried to deploy the first time a PHP application with a custom name (is here when I got that error above), how is the versioning and the naming configured? Thanks

This is the github action I run:

```
name: EB deploy
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    ## Environment variables
    env:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_DEVELOP_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_DEVELOP_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: ${{ secrets.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION }}
      AWS_APPLICATION_NAME: ${{ secrets.AWS_DEVELOP_APPLICATION_NAME }}
      AWS_ENVIRONMENT_NAME:  ${{ secrets.AWS_DEVELOP_ENVIRONMENT_NAME }}
            
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Install Python 3.9
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.9
      - name: Generate deployment package
        ## create the zip
        run: zip -r  deploy-${{ github.sha }}.zip . -x '*.png' -x '.gitignore' -x '/plugins/*/webroot/build/*' -x '*.git/*' -x '*.jpeg' -x 'build/*' -x '*.webp' -x 'config-dev-server' -x '*.JPG' -x '*/node_modules/*' -x '.env_example' -x '.htaccess' -x '/plugins/*/webroot/node_modules/*' -x 'webroot/webpack-updater/*' -x '.dockerignore' -x '.vscode' -x '*.gif' -x 'tmp/*' -x 'webroot/cypress/*' -x 'Dockerfile' -x 'docker-compose.yml' -x '*/files/*' -x 'webroot/tests/*' -x '/webroot/node_modules/*' -x '*.jpg' -x 'webroot/emails/*' 
      - name: Install EB CLI using pip
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install awsebcli
      - name: Upload package to S3 bucket
        run: |
          eb init --platform 'PHP 7.4 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2' --region  ${{ secrets.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION }} ${{ secrets.AWS_DEVELOP_APPLICATION_NAME }}
          aws s3 --region  ${{ secrets.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION }} cp deploy-${{ github.sha }}.zip s3://github/develop/
      - name: Create new ElasticBeanstalk Application Version on region ${{ secrets.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION }}
        run: |
          aws  elasticbeanstalk create-application-version \
          --application-name  ${{ secrets.AWS_DEVELOP_APPLICATION_NAME }} \
          --source-bundle S3Bucket="github",S3Key="develop/deploy-${{ github.sha }}.zip" \
          --version-label "ver-${{ github.sha }}" \
          --description "commit-sha-${{ github.sha }}"
      - name: Deploy new ElasticBeanstalk Application Version
        run: aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --environment-name ${{ secrets.AWS_DEVELOP_ENVIRONMENT_NAME }} --version-label "ver-${{ github.sha }}"
```